# Clean build in Xcode / Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode

I am new to OSX and stsarting to use XCode. Here I found the clean build options when working on my C++ project, but both are disabled, how can I use or activate them?

Thanks

Comment: i found it, just stop current debug or run, and then the clean options will appear again under build

Comment: You might want to put that solution into a proper answer and mark it answered (green v). I think that is the right procedure, to prevent your question hanging around in Unanswered ad infinitum.

Answer (score 13):

Just do a Command-Option-Shift-K this should clean the project.